# "weather is not defined" error when working with openweathermap API

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, openweathermap

I'm somewhat new to working with API's using vanilla JavaScript and I keep running into this error when trying to access the "description" within the "weather object". The console keeps reading "weather is not defined". I'm using the open weather map API. In theory I should be able to retrieve using `data.current.weather.description`. but that doesn't work, along with the other variations I've tried. Here is my current code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let long;
  let lat;
  let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector(
    ".temperature-description"
  );
  let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree");
  let locationTimezone = document.querySelector(".location-timezone");

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;

      const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      const api = `${proxy}https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&
      exclude=hourly,daily&appid=da5463709c92ab1860d3a81037565c6e`;

      fetch(api)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          const {
            temp,
            weather: { description },
          } = data.current;
          //Set DOM Elements from the API
          let kelvinToCelsius = temp - 273.15;
          temperatureDegree.textContent = kelvinToCelsius.toFixed(0);
          temperatureDescription.textContent = description;
          locationTimezone.textContent = data.timezone;
        });
    });
  } else {
  }
});
```

If anyone has ran into this issue and solved, it would be much appreciated if you filled me in.

Comment: weather is an Array . so you can't access description like that anyway - surprised you are getting the error you're getting though. you could do `weather: [{ description }]` to get the first weather description

Comment: What does your `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: The `console.log(data)` shows all the data from openweathermap. Was using that as a guide to retrieve the information I wanted.